# R - Create a new variable where each observation depends on another table and other variables in the data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I have the two following tables:

```
df <- data.frame(eth = c("A","B","B","A","C"),ZIP1 = c(1,1,2,3,5))
Inc <- data.frame(ZIP2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),A = c(56,98,43,4,90,19,59), B = c(49,10,69,30,10,4,95),C = c(69,2,59,8,17,84,30))

eth    ZIP1         ZIP2    A    B    C
A      1            1      56   49   69
B      1            2      98   10   2
B      2            3      43   69   59
A      3            4      4    30   8
C      5            5      90   10   17
                    6      19   4    84
                    7      59   95   39
```

I would like to create a variable Inc in the df data frame where for each observation, the value is the intersection of the eth and ZIP of the observation. In my example, it would lead to:

```
   eth    ZIP1   Inc        
    A      1    56
    B      1    49
    B      2    10
    A      3    43
    C      5    17
```

A loop or quite brute force could solve it but it takes time on my dataset, I'm looking for a more subtle way maybe using data.table. It seems to me that it is a very standard question and I'm apologizing if it is, my unability to formulate a precise title for this problem (as you may have noticed..) is maybe why I haven't found any similar question in searching on the forum..

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
library(reshape2)
merge(df, melt(Inc, id="ZIP2"), by.x = c("ZIP1", "eth"), by.y = c("ZIP2", "variable"))
  ZIP1 eth value
1    1   A    56
2    1   B    49
3    2   B    10
4    3   A    43
5    5   C    17
```

Comment: Ok it worked thanks a lot ! I'm still a newbie and not think hard enough to use these functions :) There were just a crash saying that variables for x and y must correspond. I changed the names for them to be the same and it still crashed then I used a simple "by" instead of "by.x by.y" and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, it can be done in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ melt(Inc, id.var="ZIP2", variable.name="eth", value.name="Inc"), 
  Inc := i.Inc
, on=c(ZIP1 = "ZIP2","eth") ]
```

The syntax for this "merge-assign" operation is `X[i, Xcol := expression, on=merge_cols]`.

You can run the `i = melt(Inc, id.var="ZIP", variable.name="eth", value.name="Inc")` part on its own to see how it works. Inside the merge, columns from `i` can be referred to with `i.*` prefixes.

---

**Alternately...**

```
setDT(df)
setDT(Inc)
df[, Inc := Inc[.(ZIP1), eth, on="ZIP2", with=FALSE], by=eth]
```

This is built on a similar idea. [The package vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) are a good place to start for this sort of syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try indeed to understand the logic. However, it seems not to work but it's my bad: I updated the post to separate the ZIP of the first and second table. Which one should I choose in your formula ? The error is: "unused argument (on = c("ZIP1", "eth"))"

Comment: @Julien Ok, I've updated for that case. I'm not sure if it works in data.table 1.9.6 (I'm running the devel version). The unused argument thing will be fixed if you run the `setDT` line first.

Comment: Thanks for the references it will be very useful for me ! Your solution seems  to still has the same crash even in using setDT. But I'll work on understanding more the merge using data.tables it will be useful for me in the long run anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

We can use `row/column` indexing

```
df$Inc <- Inc[cbind(match(df$ZIP1, Inc$ZIP2), match(df$eth, colnames(Inc)))]

df
#  eth ZIP1 Inc
#1   A    1  56
#2   B    1  49
#3   B    2  10
#4   A    3  43
#5   C    5  17
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Inc %>%
  gather(eth, value, -ZIP2) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = c("eth", "ZIP1" = "ZIP2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

my solution(which maybe seems awkward)

```
for (i in 1:length(df$eth)) {
    df$Inc[i] <- Inc[as.character(df$eth[i])][df$ZIP[i],]
}
```